# Deleting folders in cloudinary by array of folders names

Tags: node.js, express, cloudinary

is there a way to delete folders by array of their names without looping?
Maybe something like this?

```
const foldersNames = [folder1,folder2,folder3,folder4];
cloudinary.api.delete(`folder/subfolder/${foldersNames}`)});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#delete_folder, the method only take a string so it is not possible. Note that when deleting a folder, it needs to be empty so you will have to delete assets using the delete resources method.